# Which Query is more optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm wondering which is the best query which are mention below . I will have more than 100K records in each tables . I need to optimized my sql query for get better performance .

**1 st Query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    (SELECT
        id,
        name,
        city,
        country
    FROM
    VaccinationCenters 
    ) as vc
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        id as orderId,
        vendorId,
        perCardValue,
        vaccinationCenterId,
        amount,
        cardType as cardStyle,
        deliveryCharge,
        currency
    FROM
    Orders
    WHERE
    vendorId='ven001'
    )as cc
ON
    vc.id=cc.vaccinationCenterId;
```

**2nd Query**

```
SELECT
        vc.id,
        vc.name,
        vc.city,
        vc.country,
        o.id as orderId,
        o.vendorId,
        o.perCardValue,
        o.vaccinationCenterId,
        o.amount,
        o.cardType as cardStyle,
        o.deliveryCharge,
        o.currency
    FROM
    VaccinationCenters vc,
    Orders o
    WHERE
        vc.id=o.vaccinationCenterId
        AND
        o.vendorId="ven001";
```

Both of this queries give same result . i just want to know which is the best optimized query or if there is another way to optimized the transaction.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Try running an `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see what the query plans are as well as the performance.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's a performance difference.

Comment: Simply do a proper, explicit JOIN. Skip the sub-queries. Trust the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    * FROM 
    (SELECT
        id,
        name,
        city,
        country
    FROM
    VaccinationCenters 
    ) as vc INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        id as orderId,
        vendorId,
        perCardValue,
        vaccinationCenterId,
        amount,
        cardType as cardStyle,
        deliveryCharge,
        currency
    FROM
    Orders
    WHERE
    vendorId='ven001'
    )as cc ON
    vc.id=cc.vaccinationCenterId;
```

Your first query it's better because. it's get all VaccinationCenters and merge them with all Orders.

Other one get all VaccinationCenters  and get all Orders and merge them.

That's the diffrent

Comment: Thank you , But see the answer of @Wimm

Comment: Firstly you are welcome thats i know. i think it's better.

And you can enter sample data like a million and test it which one is better u will see and write here i want to learn it too.

Answer (score 0):

In opposition to the answer of EmreKalafat, I believe, that the second one is better. In the first one you create 2 independent queries and combine them. In the second one, you give the database system a good choice for optimization, especially if `vc.id`and/or `o.vaccinationCenterId`is a key.

Anyway, you can try `mysql -vv ...` (maybe in a loop with different conditions) to find out the used times. Another way is to use the performance slef testing of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the second is *definitely* better from a performance perspective.  MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries.  That means that it tends to write out subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

When it does so, it loses indexes and perhaps other useful information about the table.  This impedes the optimizer.

**Other databases do not do this.**  In other databases, the subqueries would be ignored by the optimizer.  In fact, more recent versions of MySQL have gotten better about this as well, but I still wouldn't take the chance.

Although it doesn't affect optimization, the query should be written using proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.  **Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.**

```
SELECT . . .
FROM VaccinationCenters vc JOIN
     Orders o
     ON vc.id = o.vaccinationCenterId
WHERE o.vendorId = 'ven001';
```

For this query, you want indexes on:

- `Orders(vendorId, vaccinationCenterId)`
- `VaccinationCenters(id)`

You probably already have the second index assuming that `id` is declared as a primary key.